# Inject styles on the page with help "require" when use mini-css-extract-plugin in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I specify styles as modules in order to explicitly describe the dependence of the js file on css.

I want that when i use `require ('file.css')` - in head tag on the page are automatically inject link tag with url of `file.css` .

The `style-loader` does this. But for extract content of many css files in to one file in production i want to use the `mini-css-extract-plugin`, which does not work in conjunction with `style-loader` and the documentation of which says:

> This plugin should be used only on production builds without
>   style-loader in the loaders chain, especially if you want to have HMR
>   in development.

Example of a problem: if I have several js files of "entry points" and in runtime I need to connect one of the final bundles, for example `optional-module.js`, I have to manually inject its dependencies, such as include `optional-module.css` on the page. I want the module to do this self.

How i can use `mini-css-extract-plugin` and with help `require ('file.css')` (or similar method) inject the css bundles for this files on page?